# Why won't anything appear within my frame?

Tags: java, swing

I tried this with just adding components to the frame but it had the same problem. So I created a class and a panel and I am trying it this way. But now I have the same exact problem. None of my buttons appear within the frame. I am getting an illegalargumentexception also. (this code now works) changed I made are shown below.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Pan extends JFrame {
 public Pan(){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
     JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3));

    JButton zero = new JButton(""+0);
    JButton one = new JButton(""+1);
    JButton two = new JButton(""+2);
    JButton three = new JButton(""+3);
    JButton four = new JButton(""+4);
    JButton five = new JButton(""+5);
    JButton six = new JButton(""+6);
    JButton seven = new JButton(""+7);
    JButton eight = new JButton(""+8);
    JButton nine = new JButton(""+9);
panel1.add(zero);
panel1.add(one);
panel1.add(two);
panel1.add(three);
panel1.add(four);
panel1.add(five);
panel1.add(six);
panel1.add(seven);
panel1.add(eight);
panel1.add(nine);

add(panel1);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Pan frame = new Pan();
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Number Pad");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}}
```

Comment: `void Pan()`, this is not a constructor. You never call the `Pan()` method. But I suspect that you want this to be a constructor.

Comment: It is supposed to be a constructor

Comment: So get rid of the `void` part then and make it a *real* constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exception at below line - adding container's parent to itself**

```
panel.add(panel);
```

---

One more change always call it from `EventQueue.invokeLater()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Pan frame = new Pan();
            ...
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: im still getting an error after doing panel.add(panel)

Comment: ok changed it to panel1.

Comment: Where is `panel1` declared in your code?

Comment: I just changed my code to the code that works now take alook

Comment: I think you don't need to rename it to `panel1`. You need to just remove the line `panel.add(panel);` in your prev code. I think you have solved it now just close it now and follow what I have suggested.

Comment: Please can you revert your question to make it helpful for others so that they can identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by ZouZou void Pan() is not a constructor so it won't be called. Also you might want to add the panel to the rootPane of the frame.

try this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Pan extends JFrame {
public Pan(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3));

    JButton zero = new JButton(""+0);
    JButton one = new JButton(""+1);
    JButton two = new JButton(""+2);
    JButton three = new JButton(""+3);
    JButton four = new JButton(""+4);
    JButton five = new JButton(""+5);
    JButton six = new JButton(""+6);
    JButton seven = new JButton(""+7);
    JButton eight = new JButton(""+8);
    JButton nine = new JButton(""+9);

    panel.add(zero);
    panel.add(one);
    panel.add(two);
    panel.add(three);
    panel.add(four);
    panel.add(five);
    panel.add(six);
    panel.add(seven);
    panel.add(eight);
    panel.add(nine);
    add(panel);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Pan frame = new Pan();
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Number Pad");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}}
```

Comment: why is it not a constructor

Comment: because it has void. a constructor does not specify its return

Comment: when I changed it to public, it still has an error. illegalargumentexception

Comment: try the code I pasted. that works for me.